# PHP cURL set up for Paypal mobile payments. Conversion between command window cURL call to PHP cURL script call

Tags: php, android, curl, paypal, server

After reading for sometime about cURL commands and php, I've come to the conclusion that one can execute a cURL command via the command window on the computer, or you can format a php script using cURL syntax to obtain server responses. My app is storing information in a database(000webhost). My php script stores all the available columns on my database, except the column used to store the access-token returned by Paypal-android-sdk that's needed to verify payment information for a mobile payer. I need to obtain this access-token. My php script is called via my app. This script stores information about the payer into my database along with the so called access-token. But it does not store the access-token. When I run the script on my browser, I get no errors at all. However, the $json, $jsonn and $result variables are var_dump as "false", null, null, respectively.

According to the Paypal-android-sdk documentation, one must use this script to request an access-token: (I see that i will have to run this script via the command window, I dont know how could that be when the Paypal payments will take place in actual phones not computers that have command windows). I need to translate this command window cURL set up to a php script type of set up:

here's the cURL command set up advised by Paypal:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp
:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

here's my attempt at recreating this same exact cURL command in a php script:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$idclient:$sekret");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$json = json_encode($result);
$jsonn = json_decode($json);
$tkn = $jsonn->access_token;
```

Here's how my android app will attempt to see if this cUrl inside my php script works:

```
private void dvwrt(){

 new Thread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //"http://www.myonlinedb.net/mycurlscript.php"
                        String name = "kriss";
                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            url = new URL("http://www.myonlinedb.net/mycurlscript.php");// this is when script is //accessed filling in database fields and obtaining an access-token(CANT DO //THIS)
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                        try {
                            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            conn.setDoOutput(true);
                            conn.connect();
                            OutputStream oStream = conn.getOutputStream();
                            BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(oStream, "UTF-8"));
                            String data_Write = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(stringo,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(emailString,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                                    URLEncoder.encode("phone_number", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phoneString,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                                    URLEncoder.encode("subject", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(subjectType,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                                    URLEncoder.encode("grade", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(gradeType,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                                    URLEncoder.encode("payment_id", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pay_iD,"UTF-8");
                            bWriter.write(data_Write);
                            bWriter.flush();
                            bWriter.close();
                            oStream.close();
                            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                            in.close();
                            conn.disconnect();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }).start();

            }






}
```

Comment: I actually tried replicating the PHP codes on my end and I did receive access token back. Have you tried printing the value of $json variable to make sure if you did have it?

Comment: Wow. That's great. I will try again. Maybe the 000webhost servers had a problem. Did you use the same PHP script that I posted? @vandershraaf

Comment: Yes, i used the exact same one on localhost. If you still cannot get anything from there, try turning on debug mode and see if the curl throws any error